# Transpose rows to columns in Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, transpose

I want the items in rows to be columns.

I have already set up a DBFiddle with the data. Link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=122a2865fb645e2e226928e28284c590

This is the table I have.

[image]

I want the output to be the following:

[image]

How to do this in Oracle SQL? The Sequence and the Primary key is making this confusing for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SQL> select
  2    id,
  3    max(decode(things, 'Food' , descr)) as food,
  4    max(decode(things, 'Cars' , descr)) as cars,
  5    max(decode(things, 'Sport', descr)) as sport
  6  from abc
  7  group by id
  8  order by id;

        ID FOOD       CARS       SPORT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Chicken    BMW        Soccer
         2 Mutton     Ford       Tennis

SQL>
```

---

As you asked for PL/SQL, a function that returns refcursor might be one option:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_abc return sys_refcursor is
  2    l_rc sys_refcursor;
  3  begin
  4    open l_rc for
  5      select
  6        id,
  7        max(decode(things, 'Food' , descr)) as food,
  8        max(decode(things, 'Cars' , descr)) as cars,
  9        max(decode(things, 'Sport', descr)) as sport
 10      from abc
 11      group by id
 12      order by id;
 13    return l_rc;
 14  end;
 15  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_abc from dual;

F_ABC
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

        ID FOOD       CARS       SPORT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Chicken    BMW        Soccer
         2 Mutton     Ford       Tennis


SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks, is there another alternative using PL/SQL?

Comment: You're welcome. I added some more code into the answer. Have a look, please.