# How to transpose from rows to columns in PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql

I have a table with data like the following:

| DESC_E | RPTFIELD |
| --- | --- |
| desc 1 | TITLE1 |
| desc 2 | TITLE2 |
| desc 3 | TITLE3 |

What is the best way to get result like this?

| TITLE1 | TITLE2 | TITLE3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| desc 1 | desc 2 | desc 3 |

Comment: Search via this site or your favorite search engine for `plsql PIVOT`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transpose rows to columns in Oracle Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60045996/transpose-rows-to-columns-in-oracle-sql) Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62398310/transpose-multiple-columns-into-rows.

Comment: @KenWhite I tried, but I could not get "TITLE1" ,.. as the column alias.

Comment: This seems like a task for SQL rather than PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is

(with sample data you posted)

```
SQL> with test (desc_e, rptfield) as
  2    (select 'desc 1', 'TITLE1' from dual union all
  3     select 'desc 2', 'TITLE2' from dual union all
  4     select 'desc 3', 'TITLE3' from dual
  5    )
```

Query:

```
  6  select max(case when rptfield = 'TITLE1' then desc_e end) as title1,
  7         max(case when rptfield = 'TITLE2' then desc_e end) as title2,
  8         max(case when rptfield = 'TITLE3' then desc_e end) as title3
  9  from test;

TITLE1 TITLE2 TITLE3
------ ------ ------
desc 1 desc 2 desc 3

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Littlefoot's answer is good. Just to add, you can write this more concisely with DECODE:

```
SELECT MAX(DECODE(rptfield,'TITLE1',desc_e)) title1,
       MAX(DECODE(rptfield,'TITLE2',desc_e)) title2, 
       MAX(DECODE(rptfield,'TITLE3',desc_e)) title3
  FROM test
```